# addFirst() in a custom LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm working with a LinkedList of customLinkedLists and I'm having some problems with the implementation of my AddFirst method.

Here's the method,

```
public void addFirst(GenericType data)
{
  Node<GenericType> toAdd = new Node<GenericType>(data);

  if(sizeCounter != 0)
  {
    toAdd.next = head;
    head = toAdd;
    sizeCounter++; 
  } else {
    head = toAdd;
    tail = toAdd;
    toAdd.next = null;
    sizeCounter++;
  }
}
```

The problem is this increments the size correctly every time i call it, but when I try to print out the values, it throws a null pointer exception. 
I know there's a problem in the way I'm setting the head/tail pointer but I cant figure out what it is exactly.

EDIT: 
Basically I have a OuterList and a custom LinkedList class.

in the outer list class, i have an object that makes:

```
LinkedList<CustomList<GenericType>> oList = new LinkedList<CustomList<GenericType>>;
//method add in OuterList class that calls addFirst in customLinkedClass
public void add(GenericType x){
  oList.get(0).addFirst(x);
}

//Prints the List
public void print(){
  for(int i=0; i<oList.size(); i++){
    for(int j=0; j<oList.get(i).size(); j++){
      // first .get() is for the oList to get the first customLinkedList.
      // second .get() returns the value of the Node in the customLinkedList
      System.out.println(oList.get(i).get(j));
    }
}
```

When I try to dump after adding an item it throws a null pointer. When I create the customLinkedList, is set head.next = tail. Could that be the cause of the problem? I do not see why it would be giving me errors

EDIT 2:

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
      at squarelist.CustomList.get(CustomList.java:187)
      at squarelist.OuterList.dump(OuterList.java:94)
      at squarelist.OuterList.main(OuterList.java:106)
```

Line it occurs at:

```
public GenericType get(int index){ return getNodeAt(index).value; }
```

getNodeAt() function:

```
private Node<GenericType> getNodeAt( int index ){
  Node<GenericType> p = null;
  p = head.next;
  for( int i = 0; i < index; i++ ){
    p = p.next; 
  }
  return p;
}
```

Comment: What is the variable `add`?

Comment: Can you add the code where you are getting the error?

Comment: Post the stacktrace and the line number where the exception occur

Comment: Look at the `else` part of your `if` statement: what does `add` variable contain at this point? That is what is causing your `NPE`.

Comment: @GermannArlington I corrected the mistake, the error still persists.

Comment: You still haven't post the StackTrace, and highlight the line where the exception is thrown

Comment: Posting the stacktrace will be really helpful. In the meantime, I'd bet the problem is in the get method of your CustomList.

Comment: @richardtz that is what the stacktrace points to, but I'm unsure why. I have edited the post to include the stacktrace and the get function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this :

```
head = add;
tail = add;
```

to this :

```
head = toAdd;
tail = toAdd;
```

in the else block

**EDIT**

After posting the stack trace, the problem is that you are returning null from the getNodeAt method.

Let's say that you have only one element in the list; then `p = head.next;` will be null and you are returning that value.

Try setting `p=head` instead

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake on my part, i forgot to change those. but the error is still there. Keeps throwing a null pointer

Comment: [forgot to tag] @richardtz

Comment: Thank you so much, that was causing the problem.